# Is it possible to pass an xcom into a python variable?

Tags: python, airflow

I am simply trying to get the `return` value from an xcom into a python variable, something like this:

```
datasets = S3ListPrefixesOperator(
    task_id='list_s3_prefixes',
    bucket = get_bucket(),
    prefix = 'my_key/',
    delimiter = '/'
)

bucket_keys = task_instance.xcom_pull(task_ids='list_s3_prefixes')
```

what id like to do then is to loop through each bucket key and create a `S3Copy` based on each bucket.

How do i get this accomplished?

Comment: Use dynamic task mapping

Comment: @EladKalif, what does it have to do with the question?

Comment: @user2300369 The OP wants to loop over xcom value to create operators based on each value. Thus OP has 1 operator that generates many prefixes and downstream task needs to parse each one of these outputs. That is use case for task mapping. Did you understand it differently?